# How to declare an alias of an existing math operator?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, preamble

I am wondering how to declare a command `\multinom` which should resemble the standard notation for the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients). I am trying

`\newcommand{\multinom}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}}`

in the preamble, but it does <s>not</s> produce anything similarly looking to the binomial coefficient when called with `$\multinom{n}{k}$`, <s>the `n` and `k` appear outside to the right of the parentheses.</s>

<s>How can I fix my "alias" for `\binom` from `amsmath`?</s>

---

**EDIT:** The commenters are right. This (straightforward) usage of `newcommand` works just like it should. I had accidentally left an older incorrect definition lingering in the preamble, *my apologies.*

Comment: I get the expected output. Please, make a full (but short) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: With your shown use-case, you could also just use `\newcommand{\multinom}{\binom}`...

Comment: I tried to delete the question when I realized, I had made a mistake. However, I was not allowed to delete it. So, instead I edited the question, and accepted the answer by @Sebastiano because he showed my own approach works. In fact, all answers are great. Further, I honored Sebastiano's courteous request to mark BambOo's answer as the Accepted Answer instead of his. Again, my apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just following the form of the multinomial coefficients in your link, you could do

```
\newcommand{\multinom}[3]{\binom{#1}{{#2_{1},#2_{2},...,#2_{#3}}}}
```

Example

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\multinom}[3]{\binom{#1}{{#2_{1},#2_{2},...,#2_{#3}}}}

\begin{document}
$\binom{n}{k}$
$\multinom{n}{k}{m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...what about `\multinom{n}{k}{2}`?

Comment: @Werner, For sure this could be problematic, but I wonder if it is really the purpose here. I believe the OP wants something to typeset the litteral expression not a specific numerical one.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question

Comment: @egreg While it seems my answer isn't the one finally expected by the OP, I believe it answers the statement *I am wondering how to declare a command \multinom which should resemble the standard notation for the multinomial coefficient* pretty well.

Comment: (+1) Much appreciated. I looked at the Wikipedia definition as well. In my mind a solution based on `binom` looked simplest. For me personally it not very much effort to type `\multinom{n}{k_1,k_2, ..., k_m}`, and I'd like to keep some flexibility also, e.g. to write `\multinom{n}{k_1,k_2, ...,k_j, ..., k_m}` etc.

Comment: @Jim, you are very welcome. I took your question very litteraly. I agree that flexibility is important for such notations.

Comment: @Jim Can I please ask you a kindness? Could you give the green tick to the user  BambOo that he did a good job? Thank you.

Comment: @Jim Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question, you want to use the control sequence `\multinom` instead the predefined sequence `\binom`. Both are macros with two parameters, both should behave the same. Then the most straightforward solution sounds:

```
\let\multinom=\binom
```

But maybe I don't understand something. Why to do it?

Note that Plain TeX supports a more human readable notation `{n\choose k}`.

Comment: This solution is nice, short, and to the point. Answering: *Why to do it?* First, I never liked the language "n choose k" very much for the binomial coefficient, not in high school, not in university. Second, why introduce a synonym or alias? This is simply to keep one's focus/concentration while writing a long derivation and to keep such derivations human readable on the raw (La)TeX side. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here your example works very well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\multinom}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}}    

\begin{document}
    $\multinom{n}{k}, \quad \binom{n}{k}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand{\multinom}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}}    

\begin{document}
    $\multinom{n}{k_1,k_2}, \quad \binom{n}{k}$
\end{document}
```

[image]